# Using Angular with a server-side framework

Tags: angular, flask, server, client

I'm using Flask as a server-side framework with Angular as a client-side framework.

To me it seemed fairly straightforward to reference the compiled Angular js files which sit in the `dist` folder in a `index.html` template file which Flask uses.

I have my API set up with the same Flask server.

My problem is this:

When I use `ng build` and then run `python flask-server.py` everything works fine.

But when I run `ng serve` we can only utilise the front-end logic of the app and can't communicate with the server.

Even if I ran `ng serve` and `python flask-server.py` to use the API, I'd get cross origin issues with having 2 servers communicating on my machine.

This isn't a big deal, but I'm anticipating the same problem when I'm performing testing with `ng test`. And testing is very important end to end.

Any ideas if I'm approaching this the correct way?

The only solution I can think of is to have an entirely separate server on some remote machine with the API functionality, so I can test my Angular app with `ng serve` and still call the API without any cross origin problems.

But I would like to avoid this if possible.

I would like to do both front-end and back-end development on the same machine. Including testing.

Comment: how could you have cross origin issue on a server? You are not making any cross origin requests

Comment: When I do `ng serve` it runs the Angular app on its own server.. entirely separate from Flask. The same goes for `ng test` which I need to use for testing. I.e . it runs on port 4200. When I run my Flask server it is on port 5000. Two different servers on the same machine... cross origin issues

Comment: cross origin is a browser thing. How could this issue come on two servers running on same machine?

Comment: The Angular project is served on one port using its own server which is viewed in the browser and would need access to the second server (flask)

Answer (score 0):

these two options are rational:

1. as you said you can serve all your backed code from a server which has a cross origin configuration.
2. serve your frontend(angular) and your backend on different port and set cross origin configuration;

> ng serve --port [port_number]:  ng serve --port 8080

Comment: So angular is running on port 4200; And Flask API is running in port 5000. Inside my Angular component I make a http get request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test` and get a `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present`. Any ideas?]

Comment: Fixed problem using `flask-cors` on server

Comment: @DennisCallanan

just remember to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* just to your domain, by this: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200